# How to do Azure AD groups based authorization?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

net core web api application. I have configured swagger for my web api app. I am doing authentication and authorization from swagger and I do not have webapp or SPA. Now I want to do authorization based on groups. When I saw JWT token I saw hasgroups: true rather than group ids. This is changed If more than 5 groups are associated with user. Please correct me If my understanding is wrong. So I have now hasgroups: true. So to get groups I need to call graph api. Once I get groups from graph API I need to create policies. This is my understanding and please correct me If I am on wrong track. Now I have my below web api app.

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            azureActiveDirectoryOptions = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureActiveDirectoryOptions>();
            swaggerUIOptions = Configuration.GetSection("Swagger").Get<SwaggerUIOptions>();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services
               .AddAuthentication(o =>
               {
                   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

               })
               .AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {
                   o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;

                   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {

                       ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                       {
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                       },
                   };
               });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {

                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                    TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                        { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
                });
            });
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {

                c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
                c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId });
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

I have API as below.

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public ValuesController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            string owner = (User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name))?.Value;
            var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            return owner;
        }
    }
```

Now After log in I can hit to API. Now I want to have something like Authorize(admin/user) based on the groups I want to control authorization. Now I am having trouble, where I should call graph api and get groups. Can some one help me to understand this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which protol and which flow you are using. ?

Comment: Azure v2 protocol and implicit flow

Answer (score 0):

Yes , implict flow has the limit for groups claim . To use Microsoft Graph to get current user's groups , you can try below ways :

1. Use the [on-behalf-of grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to acquire an access token that allows the API to call MS Graph as the user , [here](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core) is code sample .
2. Use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to acquire Microsoft Graph's access token in web api, this flow uses application's permission  with no user context . Code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) is  for Azure AD V1.0 using ADAL . And [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) is code sample for Azure AD V2.0 using MSAL .